# image-rendering: pixelated; on background-image: url(path);

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with both the image-rendering: pixelated; and crisp-edges; styles not applying to div containers that use a background-image: url(path).

Firefox desktop handles it fine, but Firefox on mobile and other browsers (i've checked safari and brave) don't seem to be applying the style. I would like everything to display crisp pixelated across browser platforms if possible.

*Edit: Switched back to image-rendering: pixelated; for broader browser compatibility. Firefox desktop handles everything perfectly, and is exactly how I want the site to look. Other browsers are not playing nice, and I haven't gotten any mobile browsers to work the way I'd like.*

here is my CSS for the index page

```
body {
    background-image: url(../images/aesthetiscape-index-background.png);
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}

div.gallery p {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-image: url(../images/rgb-thread-light-index.png);
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    max-width: fit-content;
    border-style: inset;
}
```

and here is a chunk of my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>aesthetiscape</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/aesthetiscape-favicon.png">
    </head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="top-index"></div>
        <div>
            <img src="images/aesthetiscape-logo.png" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="archive.html">archive</a>
            <br>
            <a href="commission.html">commission</a>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div id="draggable" class="hidden-mobile">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <img src="images/pet-rock.png">
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">

<!--    NEW POST TEMPLATE
        <div id="XXX">
            <img src="images/XXX.png">
            <p>
                XXX. XXX X, XXXX.
            </p>
        </div>
-->

        <div id="untitled 2">
            <img src="images/untitled-2.png">
            <p>
                Untitled 2. February 3, 2024.
            </p>
        </div>
```

you can also check my full repository at [aesthetiscape.github.io](https://github.com/aesthetiscape/aesthetiscape.github.io)

Attempt 0: i added image-rendering: pixelated; to img{}, which corrected the blurry rendering issue for all the images in my gallery, most important fix, works fine, I'm happy with that.

Attempts 1-2: added image-rendering: pixelated; to now non-existent callouts that were from a previous build. I realized this morning that they weren't actually doing anything and only muddied up my code, so they're out of there.

Attempt 3: added image-rendering: pixelated; to all the div.gallery p{} CSS tags I was having issues with. didn't fix the issue.

Attempt 4: tried background-size: auto; just to see if that would work, but it was not what I wanted.

Attempt 5: fixed some syntax.

Attempt 6: added background-position: top left; to problem divs because I had read that it could be an issue of the tiled images aligning oddly. didn't fix the issue.

Attempt 7: realized that background-position: was not doing anything, removed that and changed to using image-rendering: crisp-edges; because I read that some browsers respond better to that than the pixelated; style.

Attempt 8: changed defined callout .back-img {} to body {} to see if using predefined callouts would work. didn't fix the issue.

Attempt 9: flip-flopped on body/back-img. neither one fixes the issue, so I stuck with body to make things easier to read.

Comment: It seems Edge/Chrome don't support crisp-edges and Safari did have a bug see https://caniuse.com/?search=image-rendering Notes

Comment: @AHaworth unless i'm reading that wrong, it looks like it's only unsupported by older versions, and the majority of browsers do support one or the other, opera mini and internet explorer being the exceptions. If it truly is just a browser support issue, then I'll just have to leave it be, but it still seems to me like it should work.

Comment: There's a note on Chrome and Edge (4) which says no crisp-edges

Comment: @AHaworth Oh, I see what you mean. So I'm better off using pixelated, since that's supported by the majority of current browser editions, but I still have the problem that it seems not to be working on mobile. I'll switch everything back to pixelated and check again.

Comment: Still doesn’t solve the issue with the div backgrounds, but the images are showing up pixelated on Firefox, Safari and Brave. Which makes me think it’s not a browser issue, but rather something to do with the background-image: url(path); style.